# how to download a file from URL in xamarin cross platform project using PCL Support

Tags: c#, xamarin, httpclient, portable-class-library

I am new to Xamarin. Facing a lot of difficulties due to only a fraction of .Net assemblies are available for PCL.

I need to download a .db file by hitting a URL which is required to save in local drive. As the project is in PCL So this is not allowing me to use System.IO.File in my project, so making me unable to do the file operations available in .Net class library.

Ex: Suppose I am hitting the URL "http://123.com/register.db" and this returns register.db as response. I need to save the register.db as it is in my local storage.

My code to hit the URL is as below

```
public static async Task LaunchURLForSync(string targetUrl)
{
    try
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(targetUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
            using (Stream streamToReadFrom = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                string fileToWriteTo = Path.GetFileName();
                using (Stream streamToWriteTo = File.Open(fileToWriteTo, FileMode.Create)) // This doesn't work with PCL for ex. FIle.Open etc
                {
                    await streamToReadFrom.CopyToAsync(streamToWriteTo);
                }
            }
        }  
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: your code is not really working: in line 10 the function Path.GetFileName() takes a string, but your code has no parameter.

Comment: as I researched, there  is no pcl way to download and dave a file in the local storage. if you want to do this, you have to implement it on each platform

Comment: @Radinator please follow hVaughan3 way of doing it as he had answerd it. it works. you need to download the data and save it to data buffer and using PCL storage you can write it to local storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCL code only has a subset of APIs available to you. In order to get access to all of the APIs, you sometime have to write native code in each platform. I would suggest reading over Xamarin's File Storage article [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/).

I would also highly suggest using the [PCL Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/pclstorage) plugin which will allow you to easily run file related methods from your Xamarin Forms project. Xamarin actually also recommends this library.

To use PCL Storage to do what you want, after installing the library in your all of your projects, you would do the following:

```
IFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("myfile.abc", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
using (System.IO.Stream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccess.ReadAndWrite)) {
    stream.Write(buffer, 0, 100);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply. But I did find the solution from some other forum and implemented that, and it follows the exact way you mentioned. I was getting the data buffer using HttpClient and the using PCL Storage write those file to local storage